# What is the meaning of the words translated " He created" "bara" and "elohim" mean in Genesis 1:1?

Tags: word-study

Genesis 1:1 ASV In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

In the beginning
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית (bə·rê·šîṯ)
God
אֱלֹהִ֑ים (’ĕ·lō·hîm)
created
בָּרָ֣א (bā·rā)
the heavens
הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם (haš·šā·ma·yim)
and
וְאֵ֥ת (wə·’êṯ)
the earth.
הָאָֽרֶץ׃ (hā·’ā·reṣ)

Comment: You will need to clarify the question.  Are you alluding to the "us" and "we" in Gen 1:26?

Comment: @Dottard. No I am not alluding to the  "us" and "we" in Gen 1:26?

Comment: Then what are you asking?

Comment: @Dottard. It is already posted.

Comment: This question is not clear. It lacks clarity and detail.

Answer (score 3):

I presume your question is, "Is the word בָּרָ֣א (bā·rā) singular or plural?"

The answer is: Singular.

Comment: He created, correct?

Comment: @AlexBalilo, That is correct.

Comment: The answer to this question is stated very plainly in John 1:1-5. God here is clearly complicated because John says the Word was with God and the Word was God in his exposition on the first moments in Genesis.